# Bin data based on ranges of borders

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following two dataframes:

`borders`

```
start   end
25000   30000
85000   90000
105000  110000
```

... this specifies start & end of borders.

`to_bin`

```
start end
3676 4686
24943 25902
25010 26000
29000 31000
51174 52100
54224 54682
58014 59024
91987 92988
117574 119637
```

... this is my data.

I want to bin my data `to_bin` based on the borders, so all the values where at least the start is outside of e.g. `border` 1 should be in `bin_1`. *On the other side*, it is also allowed that a start is inside a border, whereas the end is outside.
Additionally, one can look at the data as if it were circular, meaning that after the last line of `to_bin`, it goes back to the first line, therefore these should all be in one bin.

Here's what I expect:

```
3676 4686   bin_1
24943 25902 bin_1                # only the start is in bin_1
25010 26000 NaN                  # no bin because fully inside border 1
29000 31000 bin_2                # only the end is in bin_2
51174 52100 bin_2
54224 54682 bin_2
58014 59024 bin_2
84900   85500 bin_2              # only the start is in bin_2
91987 92988 bin_3
117574 119637   bin_1            # everything after the last border belongs to the first bin
```

I only got so far to assign a bin if the data has both start *and end* outside a border:

```
columnname = "bin"
for index, row in borders.iterrows():
    if index == 0: # goes into first bin
        data.loc[data['end'] <= borders.iloc[[index]]['start'].item(), columnname] = "bin_1"
    elif index == borders.shape[0]-1: # goes into first bin
        data.loc[data['start'] >= borders.iloc[[index]]['end'].item(), columnname] = "bin_1"
    else:
        name = "bin_" + str(index+1)
        data.loc[(data['start'] >= borders.iloc[[index-1]]['end'].item()) & (data['end'] <= borders.iloc[[index]]['start'].item()), columnname] = name
```

This gives me:

```
start   end bin
3676    4686    bin_1
24943   25902   NaN # should be in bin_1 because of start outside border
25010   26000   NaN
51174   52100   bin_2
54224   54682   bin_2
58014   59024   bin_2
91987   92988   NaN # I don't know why this is wrong...
117574  119637  bin_1
```

*EDIT/CORRECTION*: I forgot to add the "other way round", ie. that an end can also be outside a border to be assigned a `bin`.

Answer (score 2):

Define functions:

1. *getBin* to get bin definition from a row of (a little changed) *borders*:

   ```
   def getBin(row):
       return pd.Series([pd.Interval(row.stPrev, row.start, closed='neither'),
           'bin_' + str(row.name + 1)], index=['Range', 'label'])
   ```

   Details concerning how *borders* is changed follow later.
2. *getBinName* to get the bin name for the current row (if one exists,
   either for *start* or for *end*) or *NaN* (if no bin found):

   ```
   def getBinName(row):
       # First attempt - find bin for start
       bin = bins[bins.index.contains(row.start)].label
       if bin.size > 0: return bin.iloc[0]
       # Second attempt - find bin for end
       bin = bins[bins.index.contains(row.end)].label
       if bin.size > 0: return bin.iloc[0]
       # Nothing found
       return np.nan
   ```

Start the actual processing with adding *stPrev* column to *borders*,
containing the previous value of *end* column or *0* for the first row:

```
borders['stPrev'] = borders.end.shift().fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

(print *borders* to see the result).

Then create an auxiliary DataFrame containing description of bins:

```
bins = borders.apply(getBin, axis=1)
bins = bins.append(pd.Series([pd.Interval(borders.end.iloc[-1], to_bin.end.iloc[-1],
    closed='neither'), 'bin_1'], index=bins.columns), ignore_index=True)\
    .set_index('Range')
```

For your data sample it contains:

```
                  label
Range                  
(0, 25000)        bin_1
(30000, 85000)    bin_2
(90000, 105000)   bin_3
(110000, 119637)  bin_1
```

And the last step is to generate a new column - the bin name in *to_bin*:

```
to_bin['bin'] = to_bin.apply(getBinName, axis=1)
```

The result is:

```
    start     end    bin
0    3676    4686  bin_1
1   24943   25902  bin_1
2   25010   26000    NaN
3   29000   31000  bin_2
4   51174   52100  bin_2
5   54224   54682  bin_2
6   58014   59024  bin_2
7   84900   85500  bin_2
8   91987   92988  bin_3
9  117574  119637  bin_1
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, and I appreciate your help! I am very sorry but I forgot to add the case that although the end can be outside a border, the start can be (it can be overlapping in both ways with the border). I added an example line in `data` as well.

Comment: I corrected my solution to look for both *start* and *end* (whether it is included in any bin (interval).

Answer (score -1):

Seems like i didn't understand your problem wholly. Especially why do you use condition for both start and end, when you need:

> ... all the values where at least the start is outside of e.g. border 1 should be in bin_1.

I made a piece of code with only 'start' condition.

```
to_bin['bins'] = 'NaN'  # creating new column with 'NaN' values as default
# iterating from last value in borders to the second element
for i in range(len(borders) - 1, 0, -1):  
    # iterating from last value in to_bin to the first element
    for j in range(len(to_bin) - 1, -1, -1):  
        # start value from to_bin must be between borders start/end to be assigned to bin
        if to_bin['start'][j] < borders['start'][i] and to_bin['start'][j] > borders['end'][i-1]:
            to_bin.loc[j, 'bins'] = 'bin_' + str(i+1)
        # first bin that have another (circular) condition
        elif to_bin['start'][j] < borders['start'][0] or to_bin['start'][j] > borders['end'][len(borders) - 1]:
            to_bin.loc[j, 'bins']= 'bin_1'
```

Result:

```
    start   end bins
0   3676    4686    bin_1
1   24943   25902   bin_1
2   25010   26000   NaN
3   51174   52100   bin_2
4   54224   54682   bin_2
5   58014   59024   bin_2
6   84900   85500   bin_2
7   91987   92988   bin_3
8   117574  119637  bin_1
```